# Why was Ted Beneke hiding revenue in Beneke Fabricators?

Tags: breaking-bad

I understood that Ted was hiding revenue or misrepresenting how much the company earned annually in *Breaking Bad*, but I couldn't figure out why he was doing this. To what end would hiding annual income be?

Also as a side question, what was he doing with that money?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

He was hiding the income to avoid paying the taxes as the company was having some financial difficulties.

I remember him telling Skylar how he felt everyone working there was like a family and he couldn't let the business go under so that was his motivation.

I don't think he was doing anything in particular with the money but his ain reason was avoiding taxes.

**Edit**
The business was making a profit on certain accounts. This income is taxable. By hiding the income Beneke didn't need to pay the taxes. I believe Skylar said he was recording the income as expenditure. Expenditure isn't taxable on Benekes side of the transaction. More information on these types of taxes can be found here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_tax_in_the_United_States

Comment: Hi, I'm not an American nor know how their tax law works, but how does hiding revenue mean paying less taxes, does that mean that the amount of taxable income outweighs how much net profit he has to pay his employees? Could you elaborate a bit more in layman terms please? :o)

Comment: Added in very layman terms because I'm also not from the US and know very little about it :)

Comment: If I recall correctly, they don't share any details. The company hid profits to avoid pay taxes, which means they either earned money that they never reported to the IRS (which in turn suggests that they were getting paid in cash, because other forms of payment are trivially tracked by the authorities), or they inflated expenses in order to make profitable work look unprofitable.